# Collecting data on apps in focus on OSX and iOS

Tags: ios, macos, analytics, data-collection, bigdata

I'm trying to collect information on all the applications that are being opened and used (in the fore ground and back ground) on OSX and iOS devices.
I will be using the data to gather information such as --
1. Applications being used
2. time(t), duration of active usage of application
3. Actions performed using the application
4. Applications running in the back ground

For example, on OSX, Microsoft outlook application was started at 10:00. Actively used until 10:15. Process sent to back ground (running) at 10:15. Process came back to fore ground/focus at 10.30. If possible, an action, such as an email was sent at 10:30.
Similarly, web browser activities. Pages visited and applications used.

As a hack week project, I'm trying to collect above data from different applications (initially just on mac) and use for some analysis.
I'm thinking this is possible but would like to hear from others/experts how this can be done.

Appreciate the help much. Thank you.